# Radar Chart Help2

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

So I have a Radar Chart which is working well.

I would like to make an improvement to it but not sure how to.
Currently the Radar Charts 'axis' defaults to the highest value inputted in the Fields the Radar Chart works off. For example; if the highest number entered in a Field is 7 then the axis will go up to 7. I basically want the axis to be defaulted on 10, so just always show the axis from 0 to 10, no lower no higher.

My code below;

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="RadarDemo">
    <style>
         #vfext4-ext-gen1026 {
        width:900px !important;
         }
    </style>  

        <apex:chart name="myChart" height="600" width="700" legend="false" data="{!data}">
             <apex:legend position="left" />
             <apex:axis type="Radial" position="radial"/>
             <apex:radarSeries title="7 Ps" xField="field" yField="value" tips="true" opacity="0.4"/>
        </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use minimum and maximum

```
<apex:axis type="Radial" position="radial" minimum="0" maximum="10" margin="2">
        <apex:chartLabel />
</apex:axis>
```

Please refer here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_axis.htm?search_text=apex:axis